# Kirchhoff's loop law: why doesnt the battery affect the second loop at all?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

So the explanation my textbook offers is that the power generated by the main battery is VI, which is equal to the sum of power dissipated in each resistor. hence, VI = RI^2 and V = IR. However, the other loops also use some power generated by the battery right, its not like current flow is restricted to one loop. so why should we be able to ignore all the other loops? for example, in the picture below, all the resistors have R = 2. In the top loop eq, we only consider three resistors in that loop. Shouldnt the other one have some effect atleast?
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Which is the second loop? What is the affect you’re interested in?

Comment: Which battery does your text consider the main battery?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL). This is a constraint for sum of electric voltage drops across elements in any closed loop. Obviously, voltage drop across some resistor not in the loop has nothing to do with voltage drops on elements that are in the loop - they are independent things.

Answer (score 0):

There is an effect. Your text is right, it just did not have to explain it since the resistor carrying $I_2$ does have a contribution of current and hence energy from the neighboring loop: by Kirchoff current rule: $I_2=I_1+I_3$.